# Can I train two networks, one network which contains another netwrok, at the same time?

Tags: networking, pytorch

I define two networks in my model.

```
def Net_One():
    conv2d
    conv2d
    ...
def Net_Two():
    Net_One(input)
    conv2d
    fc
```

So my question is: when I train Net_Two, using back propagation optimization, will pytorch automatically train Net_One or not? Why?

Comment: Yes, the Net_One will be trained too. Both Net_One and Net_two are connected since you get the output from the input passing through all the layers of both networks. You can find tutorials on it. For example: https://blog.paperspace.com/pytorch-101-understanding-graphs-and-automatic-differentiation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly model class name's convention should be [CapWords](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names): `NetOne`,`NetTwo`, but this doesn't hurt anything, just a convention.

As for your questions, **It depends on the processing of NetTwo().**
if the final loss of NetTwo has nothing to do with NetOne(), then the back propagation will not flow through NetOne(), and therefore will not update NetOne()'s parameters.
Otherwise the back propagation will compute the NetOne()'s gradients and update its weights.

For code samples:

```py
# NetTwo's loss has nothing to do with NetOne:
def NetOne():
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetOne, self).__init__()
        ...

    def forward(inputs):
        ...


def NetTwo():
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetTwo, self).__init__()
        ...

    def forward(inputs):
        # in this processing, temp is never used by NetTwo's layers..
        ...
        temp = NetOne(inputs)
        inputs = conv2d(inputs)
        ...
```

In the upper codes, `temp` is never used, so NetOne won't be updated when NetTwo is updating.

But if `temp` is used by NetTwo.forward(), it'll be updated, like following:

```py
def NetTwo():
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetTwo, self).__init__()
        ...

    def forward(inputs):
        # in this processing, temp is used by NetTwo's layers.
        ...
        temp = NetOne(inputs)
        inputs = conv2d(temp)
        ...
```

Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand!